# change color of value in textfield

Tags: extjs

I have an element of kind 'Ext.form.field.Text'.
I'd like to change the color of the input string in the text field.
Currently, the field is disabled and the text is being shown in a very light grey color, and I would like to change it to something diffrent.
I have tried:

```
<code>
    field.setFieldStyle('color: red  ;');
    field.fieldCls  = 'color: red  ;';
    field.cls = 'color: red  ;' 
</code>
```

All of the above had no effect on the field, or made influence on the frame around the field.
I would like to change only the text being filled in the field, nothing around...
Also, wanted to change the color of the label of the field by doing this:

```
<code>`field.setLabelCssCls('color: DarkSlateGrey  ;');`</code>
```

And it had been successfully worked, looking for eqvivalent for the text itself.

Comment: You didn't specify the ExtJS version. `field.setFieldStyle('color:red;')` works in 6.0.2 Triton, as per [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1els).

Comment: right, I forgot. extjs version 5.0.1, was not aware to the fact that it is from version 6.0.2.

Comment: The very same code works in 5.0.1-Crisp as well. Not sure what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

To make input string colorful you need to add some css. In css you need to add the color which you want.
After that call this css in `field.fieldCls` property. This default CSS class for the field input. 
Your css should be like :

```
.colorText{
    color: red;
}
```

and after putting css call this css into `field.fieldCls` like

```
 fieldCls: 'colorText',
```

I create a fiddler for you there you can check here. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1el3)

Comment: It's not working, perhaps the value being changed by extjs disabled properties, **after** my code is being rendered? how could I check for this and avoid it?

Comment: And also, you used   allowBlank: false, I was asked not to use this property, so I use "disabled" property, maybe that's why it didn't worked out...